# How to get specific characters by sed, regexp or shell skill

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I don't know how to get specific character as follows:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.1.0    interface entry 1 active
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.2.0    interface entry 1 vid
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.3.0    interface entry 1 mtu
```

I want to get characters such as "interface entry 1 active" between space and newline, but I don't know how to get it, someone can give me a suggestion ?, thanks.

Comment: have a look at `man cut`

Comment: This smacks of zero attempt and asking others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Short **awk** approach:

```
awk '{$1="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1' file
```

The output:

```
interface entry 1 active
interface entry 1 vid
interface entry 1 mtu
```

`$1="";` - sets the first field value to empty string

---

Or with ***sed***:

```
sed -n 's/^[^ ]* *\(.*\)/\1/p' file
```

Comment: To get rid of leading spaces change it to:
awk '{$1="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1'

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the prefix part is fixed-width, `cut -c 33-` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one. This works for me:

```
echo ".1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.1.0    interface entry 1 active
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.2.0    interface entry 1 vid
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.3.0    interface entry 1 mtu" | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed 's/^\s*//g'
```

Will result in

```
interface entry 1 active
interface entry 1 vid
interface entry 1 mtu
```

Comment: Thanks, it is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

1 store the text into a file:
`cat data.txt`
output is： 

`.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.1.0    interface entry 1 active
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.2.0    interface entry 1 vid
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5.1.1.6.1.1.3.0    interface entry 1 mtu`

2 use command:
`awk -F "    " '{print $2}' data.txt`
output is:

`interface entry 1 active
interface entry 1 vid
interface entry 1 mtu`

Or use the grep command:

`grep -Po "(?<=    ).+" data.txt`

output is:

`interface entry 1 active
interface entry 1 vid
interface entry 1 mtu`